# Using couchdb authentication by xmpp users

Tags: authentication, couchdb, xmpp, openfire

I'd like use couchdb for a web application with external user authentication by a XMPP-Server (Openfire). How can I achieve that? Let's say we have thre users:

- basicuser@mydomain.tld
- advanceduser@mydomain.tld
- moreadvanceduser@mydomain.tld

Now basicuser@mydomain.tld should be able to read all documents that are suited for basic users.
advanceduser@mydomain.tld should be able to read AND write all documents that are suited for basic users.
moreadvanceduser@mydomain.tld should be able to read all documents that are suited for basic and advanced users.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

following [OpenFire's Database installation Guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html), only relational Databases work directly with Open Fire:

1. MySQL
2. Oracle
3. Microsoft SQLServer
4. PostgreSQL
5. IBM DB2
6. HSQLDB

My first thought was to try and move the complete database to couchdb.

Anyways, you will need different groups for mapping the different types of users. As far as I know, read/write access in CouchDB cannot be granted or revoked for single documents, but for databases. So you will end up with 3 databases, each for one type of access level.
I am not sure if it is a good advice to hanlde document based authentication in CouchDB by "tagging" documents with authlevels.

So, I can think of different szenarios:

1. If your XMPP server ot the database
   was able to verify credentials via
   webservices, you could make use of
   that in the login procedure in your
   couchapp.
2. If there are Webservices to your Openfire backing database, you could use these to synchronize users with couchdb and map them to auth lvl groups. I think this is not a very good approach, as you will have to handle updated or deleted users as well and have another point to think about security as well. This could of course also be done by scripting on python or what ever language you prefer.
3. Use LDAP to provide auth. Does not work with CouchDB for now.
4. Maybe a good idea would be to make
   use of [Z-XMPP](http://ivan.vucica.net/zxmpp/), [strophe](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs) or
   basically any js framework that
   handles XMPP in some way?  There you
   could learn about XMPP
   authentication and maybe use this to
   verify auth credentials with XMPP. I also just learned that there is a book about ["Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery"](http://professionalxmpp.com/).

Now, these are no complete solutions provided, but something to think about, and discuss it.

Oh, and there's another Thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195083/integrating-jabber-xmpp-with-other-systems-authentication-password-sharing) at StackOverflow.

Regards, Chris